# typical operations on stored string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, linked-list

What is the Best Data Structure availaible in java to Store strings and then do some operations on it as such as:(Beginner in Java)

**Input: Sam Mohit Laksh Nitesh Aquib**

i know i can store each of them in data structures as such as *ArrayList and etc*.
But if  i store them as:

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
then  iterating and adding them as:
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
//let n be any number
{
   List.add(sc.next());
}
```

**but What if i want to Convert a Word Like Mohit to as a char array as ['M','o','h','i','t']**

so that char[0]='M' or char[3]='i'
i know i can iterate through an iterator object of type MyArrayList. but can that iterator be converted to char array ?

Comment: Do `myString.toCharArray()` to get an array of char from a String

Comment: Otherwise the question reads somewhat like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), leaving me to wonder what is the underlying problem that generated the question.

Comment: but the object is arraylist which can be accessed via iterator i think and hence toCharArray doesnot works on it. @davidxxx

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter well what if i had to compare the chars of the strings given to a given set of chars.

Comment: Then that would involve two orthogonal operations -- 1) iterating through the collection and 2) iterating through the chars of each String in the collection.

Comment: Exactly right So my question .. how to access the char part of the ArrayList object so in order to compare!

Comment: So get the String and then extract the chars from the String. Again, what confuses you about this process specifically?

Comment: Actuall i am storing the inputs in an ArrayList  which i can access by an iterator ! and suppose initially my iterator (t) points to an object Sam then t.next().toCharArray() is not supported so is there any other way i can convert the sam in arraylist to a char array??

Comment: Whether you got your `String` through an iterator, a scanner, or a static variable really doesn't matter.  Once you have a string, you can use it...  Step 1: get string; Step 2: do something with string.  Your question is entirely about Step 2; your confusion comes from trying to mix Step 1 into Step 2.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us _exactly_ what you're trying to do, including inputs, outputs, and stacktrace (if any).  It's really hard to piece all your comments into a coherent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but can that iterator be converted to char array ?

Yes `Iterator#next()` will give you string (because List has generic type String) that can be used to perform any kind of string operation. See the code below put it in main method and run.

```
    String[] str = {"Sam", "Mohit", "Laksh", "Nitesh"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
       list.add(str[i]);
    }

    Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        //here apply some condition to get your specific string object
        char[] chars = iter.next().toCharArray();
        System.out.println(chars);
    }
```

Comment: i think iterator is not required afterall Btw its also helpfull!

Comment: @imshashi17 I know we can directly use for each loop but question specifically asked for iterator that's why I used iterator to describe it will work

Answer (score 1):

I would propose ArrayList and streams for transforming in something else :

```
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add("John");
    words.add("Mohito");
```

Transformation `List<String>` to `List<char[]>`:

```
    List<char[]> asChar = words.stream()
            .map(String::toCharArray)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For transforming char[] to `List<Character>`:

```
    char[]  cc = new char[]{'a', 'b'};
    List<Character> collect1 = String.valueOf(cc)
            .chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Getting char from List:

```
String letter = collect1.get(0).toString();
```